# how could i disable or remove alert component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can disable the alert, I didn't find a boolean parameter for this in the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/alert/).

```
import React from 'react';
import Alert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';

export default function SimpleAlerts() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <Alert severity="error">This is an error alert — check it out!</Alert>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap it in a `<Snackbar>` ([doc](https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/#customized-snackbars))

```js
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true)

const handleClick = () => {
  setOpen(!open)
}

return (
  <>
    <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClick}>
      Toggle
    </Button>
    <Snackbar open={open}>
      <Alert severity="success">This is a success message!</Alert>
    </Snackbar>
  </>
)
```

Codesanbox for demo

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Answer (score 7):

Use conditional rendering:

```
import React from 'react';
import Alert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';

export default function SimpleAlerts() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      {someCondition && <Alert severity="error">This is an error alert — check it out!</Alert>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I've been using style none... this is much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

```
import Alert from "@mui/material/Alert";
import Snackbar from "@mui/material/Snackbar";


// jsx to return inside the component
return (
    // snackbar is responsible for the position for the Alert
    <Snackbar 
      // define location
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "bottom", horizontal: "center" }}
      // open and onClose needs boolean. you can set inside useState
      open={showAlert}
      onClose={closeAlert}
      // after 6 seconds it will automatically close
      autoHideDuration={6000}
    >
      <Alert severity="info">{contextHere}</Alert>
    </Snackbar>
  );
```